# How can we integrate saucelabs with using QAF automation framework?

Tags: selenium, automation, saucelabs, remotewebdriver, qaf

I am using QAF automation framework for my automation project. I want to execute my test cases on saucelabs. can anyone help me out here?

Thanks,

Albert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use remote driver and to set following properties to point your execution on sauce labs.

> ```
> remote.server=http://username:AccessKey@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
> remote.port=80
> ```

Provide appropriate driver capabilities. Refer [setting driver capabilities] documentation[1](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.9/setting_driver_capabilities.html).

**Note**: Make sure you are providing remote driver in driver name. for example

```
driver.name=firefoxRemoteDriver
```

Comment: Wow.. awesome!!! Thanks @user861594.. This is worked for me. its very easy to use..